# Mean value only of the data contained between the 1st and 3rd quartile in R

Tags: r, mean

I have concentration values for different effects, and I've been trying to calculate the mean values for every set of grouped data (by different effects), but only for the data contained between the 1st and 3rd quartile of a boxplot, by using R. I did the boxplots first (with ggplot) but I don't see how this could help. With the function ggplot_build(), I just get the quartiles. I've also tried "aggregate()", but this provides the mean for the whole set, and I don't want to include what's outside of the 1st and 3rd quartiles. Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

```
 conc.value Conc.units Effect.group           Effect
1    0.000160000    AI mg/L    systemic        Physiology
2    0.000560000    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
3    0.001090377    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
4    0.001124100    AI mg/L   cell-based        Enzyme(s)
5    0.001686150    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
6    0.002000000    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
7    0.002000000    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
8    0.002000000    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
9    0.002248200    AI mg/L   cell-based        Enzyme(s)
10   0.002248200    AI mg/L   cell-based        Enzyme(s)
11   0.002248200    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
12   0.002248200    AI mg/L   cell-based     Biochemistry
13   0.004000000    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
14   0.004000000    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
15   0.004496400    AI mg/L   cell-based     Biochemistry
16   0.004496400    AI mg/L   cell-based        Enzyme(s)
17   0.004496400    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
18   0.005000000    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
19   0.005000000    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
20   0.005000000    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
21   0.005000000    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
22   0.005000000    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
23   0.005000000    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
24   0.005000000    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
25   0.005000000    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
26   0.005000000    AI mg/L    systemic        Population
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the stats included in the boxplots. Here's some illustrative data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(rnorm(100))
)
```

Now store the boxplot of your column `V1`as an object, called here, well,  `object`:

```
object <- boxplot(df$V1)
```

Inspect the statistics internally associated with `object`:

```
object$stats
            [,1]
[1,] -1.96661716
[2,] -0.49667731
[3,]  0.06175631
[4,]  0.69499808
[5,]  2.18733299
```

The 2nd and 4th values delimit the IQR (to check, you can do `summary(df)`). So the next step would be to *subset* `df$V1`on those two values and calculate the mean:

```
mean(df$V1 >= object$stats[2] & df$V1 <= object$stats[4])
[1] 0.5
```

This is, *in nuce*, how you can solve the issue. As it seems you have a more complex dataframe than this, this solution will obviously have to be adapted to your data. If you need help with that, you need to show what the data looks like.

For example, if you have a dataframe with several numerical variables, you can do the calculation in one go like this:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(rnorm(100)),
  V2 = c(rnorm(100, 1)),
  V3 = c(rnorm(100, 2))
)

lapply(df[,1:3], function(x)  mean(x >= object$stats[2] & x <= object$stats[4]))
$V1
[1] 0.5

$V2
[1] 0.39

$V3
[1] 0.07
```

**EDIT**:

For a dataset such as the one you describe in your recent comment, the solution could be this:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(rnorm(100)),
  Effect = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace = T)
)
```

To calculate the means for the interquartile range by `Effect`, you can do this in one go:

```
tapply(df$V1, df$Effect, function(x)  mean(x[x >= quantile(x, 0.25) & x <= quantile(x, 0.75)]))
           A            B            C            D 
 0.005502653  0.251196882  0.077304685 -0.108590409
```

Comment: In your example, when you do "mean(df$V1 >= object$stats[2] & df$V1 <= object$stats[4])", how can you tell that the result 0.5 included all datapoints between the 1st and 3rd quartile? As I see it here, you're just subsetting the specific numerical value for the quartiles, and not the data in it.

Comment: No, notice the use of  `>=`and `<=`: `mean(df$V1 >= object$stats[2] & df$V1 <= object$stats[4])` says: calulate the means of that range of `df$V1` that is greater than or equal to `object$stats[2]`and smaller than or equal to `object$stats[4]`. That is, you subset `df$V1`on those two numerical values.

Comment: See **EDIT** in the answer.

Comment: What if I have 20 values that are the same, and then other different values. If I do, "mean(df$V1 >= object$stats[2]...". Wouldn't the software understand "all those values that are equal to that specific value (the 1st quartile)", regardless of how many I have? This definitely will affect the mean value.

Comment: But that's the nature of how the mean is calculated! It does not discriminate identical and different values. The mean is a measure of central tendency and if certain values get repeated then that repetition will of course have an impact on the mean, and rightly so!

Comment: My comment was misunderstood. When you type this code: "mean(df$V1 >= object$stats[2] & df$V1 <= object$stats[4])". You're not saying that "object$stats[4]" is a quartile but a mere number. Then, if data contains repetitive values, the code will take even those that are outside the quartiles because they're numerically the same. Take this simple example: data = 2,4,7,7,7,7,7,9,9,9,15,15,15,15; 1st q=7, 3rd q=15. If I do: mean(df$V1 >= object$stats[2] & df$V1 <= object$stats[4]), it will take: >=7 & <=15. Then, mean result will be = 10.17, but it's actually 8.75. I hope I could make it clear

Comment: Okay, if you have `data <- c(2,4,7,7,7,7,7,9,9,9,15,15,15,15)`, then `quant <- quantile(data)` followed by 
`mean(data[data >= quant[2] & data <= quant[4]])` gets you what you want. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @user1407 I'd be grateful if you could let me know whether the latest solution works for you.

Comment: I used subset to split my data set by effects. Then I used your code "quant <- quantile(data) followed by mean(data[data >= quant[2] & data <= quant[4]])" to calculate mean of data contained in the IQR, per each effect group. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `quantile` function. Using the same data as @Chris

```
quantile(df$V1)
         0%         25%         50%         75%        100% 
-2.30916888 -0.49385424  0.06175631  0.69181917  2.18733299
```

You can get the values, by the index `quantile(df$V1)[1]` or by using the `probs` option

```
> quantile(df$V1,probs=.25)
       25% 
-0.4938542
```

Once you have the data, simply subset and calculate the mean (as @Chris) pointed out

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly create a new function which outputs the quantile group of each element in a given vector:

```
qgroup = function(numvec, n = 4){

  qtile = quantile(numvec, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/n), na.rm = T)
  out = sapply(numvec, function(x) sum(x >= qtile[-(n+1)]))

  return(out)
}

> qgroup(seq(1:20))
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

Now, apply this function on a numeric vector `nums` in a `data.table` or `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(123)
nums = rnorm(100)

#data.table
dt = data.table(nums)[, Qnums := qgroup(nums)]

#data.frame
df = data.frame(nums)
df$Qnums = qgroup(df$nums)
```

Lastly, subset the data object according to `Qnums` and calculate the mean of the numeric column `nums`:

```
> dt[Qnums %in% c(2,3), mean(nums)]
[1] 0.05432868

> mean(df$nums[df$Qnums %in% c(2,3)])
[1] 0.05432868
```